# Creating a table with two foreign keys fail

Tags: mysql

Suppose I want to create a table for a login page to hold username and password and reference it in other tables for storing roles.

```
CREATE TABLE Login (
 username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

Create Table User (
 username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
 password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(password) REFERENCES Login(password), 
 FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES 
 Login(username)
);
```

It seems relevant to include password because it needs to be a not null field when inserting data. Table User might have an integer for storing roles or something similar but I tried to simplify it a bit for this example.

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'databasename.user' (errno:150)

Error 150 is a type mismatch but they appear to be the same type - not null and varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key can only point to a unique field.... Primary key fields are implicitly unique. But password is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key is only one in the Login table but you create two foreign key which trigger the only one primary key in your Login table

```
CREATE TABLE Login (
 username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

Create Table User (
 username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
 password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES 
 Login(username)
);
```